# Library compiles, but won't run

Tags: c++, arduino

I wrote some code to drive an external 7 Segment display using an Arduino Uno board.  When run in the Arduino IDE as an .ino file it worked perfectly.  I then decided I wanted to turn it into a library for future use. I created my .h and .cpp files, but when I try to use the same functions which worked before as .ino, they now won't work. Here's my code:

.ino

```
#include <Segment.h>

Segment seg;

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
  seg.display(1);
}
```

.h

```
#ifndef Segment_h
#define Segment_h
#include "Arduino.h"

class Segment
{
  public:
    Segment();
    void display(int i);
  private:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;
    int f;
    int g;
    int dot;
};
#endif
```

.cpp

```
#include "Segment.h"

  const int a=6;
  const int b=7;
  const int c=8;
  const int d=10;
  const int e=11;
  const int f=13;
  const int g=12;
  const int dot=9;

Segment::Segment()
{
  pinMode(a, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(b, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(c, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(d, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(e, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(f, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(g, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dot, OUTPUT);
}

void Segment::display(int i)
{
  if (i==0){
    digitalWrite(a, LOW);   
    digitalWrite(b, LOW);
    digitalWrite(c, LOW);
    digitalWrite(d, LOW);
    digitalWrite(e, LOW);   
    digitalWrite(f, LOW);
    digitalWrite(g, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(dot, HIGH);
  }  

  else if (i==1){
    digitalWrite(a, HIGH);   
    digitalWrite(b, LOW);
    digitalWrite(c, LOW);
    digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(e, HIGH);   
    digitalWrite(f, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(g, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(dot, HIGH);
  }

  else if (i==2){
    digitalWrite(a, LOW);   
    digitalWrite(b, LOW);
    digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(d, LOW);
    digitalWrite(e, LOW);   
    digitalWrite(f, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(g, LOW);
    digitalWrite(dot, HIGH);
  }

  else if (i==3){
    digitalWrite(a, LOW);   
    digitalWrite(b, LOW);
    digitalWrite(c, LOW);
    digitalWrite(d, LOW);
    digitalWrite(e, HIGH);   
    digitalWrite(f, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(g,LOW);
    digitalWrite(dot, HIGH);
}
  else if (i==4){
    digitalWrite(a, HIGH);   
    digitalWrite(b, LOW);
    digitalWrite(c, LOW);
    digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(e, HIGH);   
    digitalWrite(f, LOW);
    digitalWrite(g, LOW);
    digitalWrite(dot, HIGH);
  } 
  else if (i==5){
    digitalWrite(a, LOW);   
    digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(c, LOW);
    digitalWrite(d, LOW);
    digitalWrite(e, HIGH);   
    digitalWrite(f, LOW);
    digitalWrite(g, LOW);
    digitalWrite(dot, HIGH);
  }
  else if (i==6){
    digitalWrite(a, LOW);   
    digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(c, LOW);
    digitalWrite(d, LOW);
    digitalWrite(e, LOW);   
    digitalWrite(f, LOW);
    digitalWrite(g, LOW);
    digitalWrite(dot, HIGH);
  }
  else if (i==7){
    digitalWrite(a, LOW);   
    digitalWrite(b, LOW);
    digitalWrite(c, LOW);
    digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(e, HIGH);   
    digitalWrite(f, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(g, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(dot, HIGH);
  }
  else if (i==8){
    digitalWrite(a, LOW);   
    digitalWrite(b, LOW);
    digitalWrite(c, LOW);
    digitalWrite(d, LOW);
    digitalWrite(e, LOW);   
    digitalWrite(f, LOW);
    digitalWrite(g, LOW);
    digitalWrite(dot, HIGH);
  }
  else if (i==9){
    digitalWrite(a, LOW);   
    digitalWrite(b, LOW);
    digitalWrite(c, LOW);
    digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(e, HIGH);   
    digitalWrite(f, LOW);
    digitalWrite(g, LOW);
    digitalWrite(dot, HIGH);
    }

  else if (i==10){
    digitalWrite(a, HIGH);   
    digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(e, HIGH);   
    digitalWrite(f, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(g, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(dot, LOW);
  }

  else if (i==11){
    digitalWrite(a, HIGH);   
    digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(e, HIGH);   
    digitalWrite(f, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(g, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(dot, HIGH);
  }
}
```

The compiler gives no errors, but the SSD is just blank.  I ran a test function in the .cpp file called `int test()`, which just returned an arbitrary number, and it worked fine. this makes me think that the includes are working as they should, and all three files are communicating.  I'm thinking that for some reason it's not recognizing the `#include "Arduino.h"` for some reason, which is killing my `digitalWrite()` and `pinMode` functions.  Can anybody shed some light on this for me? Thanks.

Comment: You have a thru g as both member variables of Segment and global const.  Since all your references to these are in class member function, C++ will use the member variables which are not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

As Brian pointed out in his comment, you have variables a, b, c, d, e, f, g, and dot defined in your Segment class as private members and you redefine them as global constants.  When calling pinMode() and digitalWrite() within Segments member functions, the functions use the class member variables, which haven't been initialized, instead of your global variables which you have initialized.

In your Segment constructor, before calling pinMode(), initialize your member variables.

Comment: So I moved the `const` definitions to inside `Segment()`, but now all 7 segments plus the dot light up, which means the variables still aren't working as they should.

Comment: You shouldn't move the const definitions inside the constructor, you should remove them and initialize the member variables. If you need the members to be const just use the member initializer list.  Perhaps try explicitly turning the segments off after setting each pin mode.

Comment: Awesome. That worked perfectly.  I used an initialization list in the `Segment()` constructor.  Would somebody explain how come it needs to be done that way though? Thanks again.

Comment: When you moved the variables into the constructor, you bypassed the member variables again, and the function local variables were used.  After setting the pin modes, your variables fell out of scope and were bogus values when you called display().  By initializing them correctly in the constructor, the variables contained valid data for display() to use.  For further information, look into c++ variable scope.